# generate new html files on server- grails

Tags: html, grails, auto-generate

How do I go about programmatically creating new HTML pages (views) in grails from the controller and then fill it with data from the database. The data and name of the pages will be different for each new page but the formatting of all the pages is exactly the same. 
Is there any library in grails that does that?
Snippets are welcome.

Comment: Seems that it's described on _every_ basic tutorial for grails. Did you read any? As I see you alredy knowns what is it Controller, View (GSP), HTML, MVC. Any specific question? Any problems with passing data to view?

Comment: I don't want to manually create the gsp in the view.. that should also be generated automatically.

Comment: Ok, it's not a grails job. Probably you can find and standalone tool for generating GSP files, but i'm not sure that such even exists. Also, you must be understand that you cant do it on the fly, on deployed app, only before deployment

Comment: I am trying to store a lot of different data sets from the database in form of HTML pages, some sort of HTML reports you can say.

Comment: and each of them have so uniq layout, so you're trying to generate gsp for each???

Comment: there layout is same but have to store each data set in a different static html page on the server.

Comment: what you need to store it as static html file? why not to use database?

Comment: oh, seems that I got it. Do you want to store result of view rendering somewhere on server as plain html file?

Comment: yes exactly! How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get any render result as a string, just by:

```
String report = render(controller: 'report', view: 'basic', model: [])
```

If you're making this reports in service, you should use `pageRenderer` bean, like:

```
import grails.gsp.PageRenderer

class ReportService {
    PageRenderer pageRenderer


    def makeReport() {
        String report = pageRenderer.render(controller: 'report', view: 'basic', model: [])
        //save 'report' to a file
    }
}
```